# Set the current GMT time in HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

```
searchAudit = () => {
        let formInfo = {}
        formInfo = { ...this.state.formData }
        formInfo.from_tstamp = (formInfo.from_tstamp) ? moment(formInfo.from_tstamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z') : ''
        formInfo.to_tstamp = (formInfo.to_tstamp) ? moment(formInfo.to_tstamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z') : ''
        this.props.getAudit(formInfo)
    }
```

I'm Expecting `2021-03-01 18:32:48` this format,that time should be in GMT time ,the date will be from Date picker

Here I want to set the current time in GMT in HH:mm:ss format,Ive used 'z' at the last in moment.format() but its giving wrong result, i want the GMT time to set to from_stamp and to_tstamp.Please Help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the result you are getting, and what is the desired result?

Comment: Actually i wait like, 2021-03-01 18:32:48 this format

Comment: What is the result you are currently getting?

Comment: 2021-03-01 00:00:00

Comment: May you also share what `formInfo.from_tstamp` is?

Comment: That's from state, it holds the default selected date() string